# How can I get snappy to list all available snap packages?

Tags: snap

I already know about "sudo snap find", but this doesn´t show all snap packages. Output:

```
 ~ $ sudo snap find
Name                              Version                       Developer            Notes  Summary
ag-mcphail                        1.0.1                         njmcphail            -      The Silver Searcher - mcphail's build and upstream git version
archaeopteryx                     2                             redmar               -      Visualization, Analysis, and Editing of Phylogenetic Trees
balloon-pop                       1.0                           1bsyl                -      balloon popper game & puzzle
blender-tpaw                      2.77a                         tpaw                 -      Blender is the free and open source 3D creation suite.
bubble-pop                        1.0                           1bsyl                -      bubble popper game & puzzle.
cactpot-solver                    1.1                           cyborgcentral        -      A tool for finding the best mini-cactpot card choices
champ                             0.0.1~git                     si-dz0ny             -      Plex 2nd screen player
checkbox-snappy                   0.9~s16                       ce-certification-qa  -      Testing tool for Snappy Ubuntu Core (best installed with --devmode for the moment)
ci-dice                           0.1                           beisner              -      Console dice roller tool for CI pass/fail simulation
cla-check                         0.1                           kyrofa               -      Check if Canonical's Contributor License Agreement has been signed
click-parser                      3.0.5                         bhdouglass           -      Extract data from Ubuntu's click & snap packages
conjure-up                        2.0.0.7                       adam-stokes          -      Package runtime for conjure-up spells
connect4                          1.0                           1bsyl                -      4 in a Line/Row game
cpustat                           0.01.27-20160726-227-77e2615  cking-kernel-tools   -      periodic cpu utilization statistics
darktable-kyrofa                  2.0.5snap1                    kyrofa               -      Virtual lighttable and darkroom for photographers
dash-shell                        0.5.9                         anthonywong          -      POSIX-compliant shell
deadbeef-vs                       0.7.2-snap1                   vs                   -      The Ultimate Music Player
demo-amd64                        1.1                           woodrow              -      AMD64 generic package
demo-wget                         1.17.1                        woodrow              -      retrieves files from the web
dragonboard                       16.04-0.3                     canonical            -      Dragonbaord support package
dstat-jamiebennett                0.7.3                         jamiebennett         -      Dstat is a versatile replacement for vmstat, iostat, mpstat, netstat and ifstat.
electrum-tpaw                     2.6.4-tpaw3                   tpaw                 -      Lightweight Bitcoin Client
explode-bricks                    1.1                           1bsyl                -      very Simple Bricks game
fiemap                            0.0.1                         cking-kernel-tools   -      file extent dumping tool
freecell-solitaire                1.0                           1bsyl                -      FreeCell Solitaire, card game
game-2048                         1                             dholbach             -      2048 puzzle game
go16-lbo                          1.6.3                         lbo                  -      Go programming language compiler
gtwang-demo                       1.0                           gtwang               -      G.T.Wang demo application.
hello-bluet                       0.1                           bluet                -      Qt Hello World example
hello-gabriell                    0.1                           gabriell             -      Qt Hello World example
hello-sergiusens                  1.0                           sergiusens           -      hello world example
hello-stgraber                    2.10                          stgraber             -      GNU Hello, the "hello world" snap
ipython-example                   5.0.0                         frankban             -      Enhanced interactive Python shell
ivoks-vim                         7.4                           ivoks                -      ivoks's VIM
jtiledownloader                   0.6.1-1                       ogra                 -      Download OSM maps
juju-nskaggs                      2.0-beta13                    nskaggs              -      juju client
kernelscan                        0.0.1                         cking-kernel-tools   -      fast kernel source error message scanner
kt                                1.0                           bjf                  -      Ubuntu Kernel Team Tools
laidout                           0.096.1-2                     ogra                 -      Desktop Publishing
liteide-tpaw                      x30.2-tpaw1                   tpaw                 -      LiteIDE is a simple, open source, cross-platform Go IDE.
livetuner                         0.1                           cyborgcentral        -      a GUI for livestreamer
mahjong-game                      1.0                           1bsyl                -      Mahjong game, a one-player game. Based on SDL2
minesweeper                       1.0                           1bsyl                -      Minesweeper game
miniterm-joc                      1                             jocave               -      pySerial miniterm in a snap
modem-manager                     1.4.0-1                       canonical            -      ModemManager is a service which controls mobile broadband
mongo22                           2.2.7                         niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mongo24                           2.4.14                        niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mongo26                           2.6.12                        niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mongo30                           3.0.12                        niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mongo32                           3.2.7                         niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mongo33                           3.3.9                         niemeyer             -      MongoDB document-oriented database
mup-accounts                      2016.07.01                    niemeyer             -      mup IRC and Telegram bot - account connection side
mup-plugins                       2016.07.05                    niemeyer             -      mup IRC and Telegram bot - plugins side
neovim-kalikiana                  0.1.4                         kalikiana            -      Vim-fork focused on extensibility and agility.
nethack                           3.4.2-2                       ogra                 -      The popular nethack console adventure
nitrokey-app                      0.4snap1                      nitrokey             -      Nitrokey Application
ntpserver                         0.1                           cargonza             -      ntp server snap app
osddm                             4.1.3.901-snap1               vs                   -      Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler
overlay                           0.1                           kyrofa               -      Tools for assisting with debugging read-only squashfs snaps via overlayfs
packageproxy                      0.1                           ogra                 -      approx based package proxy running on port 9999
pc                                16.04-0.2                     canonical            -      AMD64 generic package
pc-kernel                         4.4.0-31                      canonical            -      The canonical generic amd64 kernel
podpublish                        20160610+git5ddfa04-1         flexiondotorg        -      A tool for encoding and publishing podcast content and assets
polonium                          v0.5.1                        rgrannell1           -      Polonium is a stateless password manager based on PBKDF2.
qownnotes                         16.08.0                       pbek                 -      Plain-text file notepad with markdown support and ownCloud integration
readtsc                           0.0.1                         cking-kernel-tools   -      Intel x86 Time Stamp Counter read
reversu                           1.0                           1bsyl                -      ReversU is strategy board game with black & white tokens
robomongo                         0.9.0-rc9                     frankban             -      MongoDB management tool
rpgdiceroller                     1.7                           quality-mix          -      A dice roller with simple GUI
rpgen                             v0.1.0                        rgrannell1           -      compile multiple scripts into a single cloud-init friendly script
serial-vault                      0.7                           james                -      Serial Vault Service
simple-cprov                      0.4                           cprov                -      This is a test snap
snapstore-example                 0.3                           noise                -      Minimalist example snap store
so-hello-world                    0.2                           shadowen             -      the old classic
solitaire                         1.0                           1bsyl                -      usual Solitaire card game, as known as Patience or Klondike
speed-test                        1.7.0.1                       bartaz               -      Test your internet connection speed and ping using speedtest.net from the CLI
spider-solitaire                  1.0                           1bsyl                -      Spider Solitaire card game
sudoku-game                       1.0                           1bsyl                -      Sudoku 9x9 game
taskwarrior-plars                 2.5.1-1                       pwlars               -      feature-rich console based todo list manager
teatime                           16.07                         paroj                -      Simple egg timer application for the Unity Desktop
test-snapd-cups-control-consumer  1.0                           canonical            -      Basic cups-control consumer snap
test-snapd-fuse-consumer          1.0                           canonical            -      Basic fuse consumer snap
test-snapd-tools                  1.0                           canonical            -      Tools for testing the snapd application
tftp-hpa-jhobbs                   0                             jason-hobbs          -      Trivial File Transfer Protocol Client
torgo                             1.3.0                         tros                 -      A Logo interpreter written in Java.
tuxguitar-vs                      1.3.2-snap2                   vs                   -      TuxGuitar
u1test20160725                    1.0                           u1test20160720       -      Simple dd like tool
u1test20160920                    0.1                           u1test201607192      -      Summary of the most simple snap
uappexplorer-cli                  1.0.0                         bhdouglass           -      Browse uApp Explorer right for the command line!
uname-a                           1.0                           hungnhp              -      The test "uname -a" snap
unofficial-hexchat                2.12.1                        diddledan            -      HexChat IRC Client
upnp-server                       0.1.0                         ogra                 -      upload files with WebDAV and serve them via DLNA/UPnP
vlc                               daily                         videolan             -      The ultimate media player
vuze-vs                           5.7.2.0-snap1                 vs                   -      Vuze is a powerful, open source, bittorrent client.
wallpaperdownloader               2.0                           egarcia              -      Download and manage your favorite wallpapers from the Internet
x86latency-test                   0.0.1                         cking-kernel-tools   -      Intel x86 kernel timer latency test
x86rdrand-benchmark               0.0.1                         cking-kernel-tools   -      Intel x86 rdrand CPU benchmark
xcape-lbo                         7fca364                       lbo                  -      Modify keys to act as other keys
xkcdpass-codersquid               0.1                           codersquid           -      Generate secure multiword passwords/passphrases, inspired by XKCD
xlsx                              git                           tealeg               -      Convert microsoft XLSX files into CSV files.
```

Examples:

1. I can install a snap package called "libreoffice", but it isn´t listed by this command: "sudo snap find"
2. There is a package called "telegram-sergiusens", also installable, but not listed.

How can i list ALL packages?

Comment: uappexplorer-cli doesn't appear to support a proxy, it doesn't read the system or environment settings for a proxy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Note that sudo isn't necessary. `snap find` and `snap install` will work just fine without it.*

`snap find` only shows promoted and public snaps in the stable channel. By curating snaps in this way, users can expect a degree of quality when using `snap find` for app discovery.

If you'd like to know all the snaps that exist, try [uappexplorer](https://uappexplorer.com/apps?type=snappy):

```
$ snap install uappexplorer-cli
$ uappexplorer-cli --type snap
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ App                │ Description               │ Type          │ ❤    │ ★    │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼──────┤ 
│ test-snapd-cups-c… │ A basic snap declaring a… │ Snap          │ 0    │ 0    │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼──────┤ 
│ test-snapd-fuse-c… │ A basic snap declaring a… │ Snap          │ 0    │ 0    │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼──────┤ 
│ lcavassa-iperf     │ A TCP, UDP, and SCTP net… │ Snap          │ 0    │ 0    │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼──────┤ 
│ deadbeef-vs        │ The Ultimate Music Playe… │ Snap          │ 0    │ 0    │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────┼──────┤
```

Comment: Really ?
# snap install ohmygiraffe
error: access denied (try with sudo)

Comment: Once you "snap login" sudo is no longer required.

Comment: This does not work. It does not show all snaps.

Comment: As today it does not work on Ubuntu Xenial desktop amd64. Where I/we can report bug about that?

Comment: Who says that snap install works `without sudo`?

Comment: https://uappexplorer.com/?type=snappy has shut down. Please adapt the post or remove it.

Answer (score 8):

1. Install [SnapWeb](https://github.com/snapcore/snapweb) which is a "Beautiful and functional interface for snap management"

   ```
   sudo snap install snapweb
   ```
2. Go to http://localhost:4200 using your browser of choice.

Enjoy.

Comment: This is unrelated, but if you have [shellinabox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/shellinabox) installed it will use the same port.

Answer (score 7):

It's not documented, but a list of snaps is kept in the file `/var/cache/snapd/names` (it contains all known snaps in the stable channel [according to Alan Pope](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/af9gjf/snap_flatpak_appimage_from_a_software_deployment/ee1da8q/)). You can inspect that file by hand to see what snaps are available, if you're happy with potentially missing a few that aren't available in the stable channel, and those that aren't in the default snap store.

I think you can also query the store directly by sending a request to `https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/names`, but it's not clear what the correct values for the required headers are, and it's heavily rate-limited. Further, it appears to return a strict subset of the names available in `/var/cache/snapd/names` anyway, so you're probably better off just looking at that file.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested command above, shows only a small list of available snaps

```
~$ uappexplorer-cli --type snap
```

To Count the lines with snaps of the command above:

```
~$ uappexplorer-cli --type snap | grep '│' | wc -l
31
```

Only 31 Snaps?

I figured out another command, that shows a much bigger list of available snaps

```
~$ sudo snap find $
```

But I am not sure if this are really **all** available snaps

```
~$ sudo snap find $| wc -l
101
```

or

```
~$ sudo snap find .| wc -l
101
```

or many others like % - , ö ä ü and so on...
shows (only) 101 available snaps today 2016-02-14

Comment: "$" doesn't work, "%" does

Comment: In this regard, apt together with dpkg seems to be much better. Is it really necessary to download another tool like uappexplorer or snapweb?

Comment: sudo snap find %| wc -l: 101

Answer (score 0):

1. use Zsh and type the command below followed with the tab key (⇥)
2. answer with y(es)

you will see all available snap packages (I think)

**% sudo snap install** tab key (⇥)

zsh: do you wish to see all 4305 possibilities (861 lines)?

^C or select one of them you want to install ...

to see all snap packages beginning with "a"

**% sudo snap install a** tab key (⇥)

zsh: do you wish to see all 200 possibilities (40 lines)?

Zsh is nice!

Comment: bash does this too now, FWIW.